# How do I take a list of 8 digit numbers in an Excel, and give each digit its own row?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have an Excel list of numbers `{12345, 12354, 12435, etc...}`. I want to output a list that has one row for each digit `{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,5,4,1,2,4,3,5, etc...`}.

Open to any suggestions!

**Edit:** (From comments)
Sample Data:
[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: @StevenMartin He wrote: *"I have an Excel list of numbers {12345, 12354, 12435, etc...}."* Is that the list for whose whereabouts you are asking?

Comment: His use of list is vague , its written twice in the question with completely different meaning.  i meant are they in a data validation list of just in 1 cell which wouldnt be called a list but i think he means just that

Comment: Perhaps list is a confusing term. I have many records that are just all combinations of 12345, like this http://i.imgur.com/93lFEyx.png.

I want to convert it to this: http://i.imgur.com/aponhCq.png

Answer (score 0):

With your list in **A1** run this macro:

```
Sub SplitApart()
    Dim K As Long, i As Long, L As Long
    Dim r As Range, vv As String, v As String
    Set r = Range("A1")
    v = r.Value
    L = Len(v)
    K = r.Row + 1

    For i = 1 To L
        vv = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(vv) Then
            Cells(K, 1).Value = vv
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To produce:

[image]

The code will work on arbitrary comma-separated data in a single cell

Answer (score 0):

In my answer your origin data is in column `A` and are numbers.
Then With running this macro you will have your results in the next column (`B`).

```
Sub splitByDigits()
    Dim sourceColumnNumber as integer
    Dim destinationColNumber as integer
    sourceColumnNumber = 1         ' For reading from column A
    destinationColNumber = 2       ' For writing to column B

    Dim strValue As String
    Dim net As Integer, pow As Integer
    Dim resultRow As Long

    resultRow = 1

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
        strValue = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, sourceColumnNumber).Value & " ")
        If (strValue = "") Then Exit For

        net = Val(strValue)
        pow = Len(strValue) - 1

        While (net > 0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(resultRow, destinationColNumber).Value = Fix(net \ 10 ^ pow)
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
            net = net Mod 10 ^ pow
            pow = pow - 1
        Wend
    Next i
End Sub
```

And ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SplitDigits()
    Dim rngLastCell As Range, tmpCell As Range
    Dim x As Integer, rngTarget As Range

    Set rngLastCell = Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp)
    Set rngTarget = Range("B1")

    For Each tmpCell In Range("A1", rngLastCell.Address)
        For x = 1 To Len(tmpCell.Value)
            rngTarget = Mid(tmpCell.Value, x, 1)
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1)
        Next x
    Next tmpCell
End Sub
```